# iOS - How to discover unadvertised services on a BLE peripheral

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I got this Nordic nRF52 BLE peripheral which doesn't advertise its services. I'm able to connect to it, but can't discover services on iOS. Since I know the service UUIDs, I've tried to pass them to the `discoverServices` function. But this does not work.

After about 30 seconds it finally disconnects.

On the peripheral the GAP advertising flag is set to `General Discoverable`. Using apps like `LightBlue` or `nRF Connect` I see the name and UUID of the peripheral but no service. When connecting with the LightBlue app, after a few seconds an error (`Timeout interrogating the peripheral`) is shown.

On Android discovering the unadvertised services works just fine.

As of the [Core Bluetooth Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/PerformingCommonCentralRoleTasks/PerformingCommonCentralRoleTasks.html), it should basically work:

> After you have established a connection to a peripheral, you can explore its data. The first step in exploring what a peripheral has to offer is discovering its available services. Because there are size restrictions on the amount of data a peripheral can advertise, you may discover that a peripheral has more services than what it advertises (in its advertising packets). You can discover all of the services that a peripheral offers by calling the peripheral’s discoverServices: method, like this: `[peripheral discoverServices:nil];`

Does anyone know what the differences in the SDKs are and if there is a possibility to discover unadvertised services on iOS like Android does?

I've read that iOS is capable of connecting directly, skipping the discovery process, when the peripheral is cached. But having the peripheral cached, it needs to be paired once. Is there maybe a way to set the cache manually?

Appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: "I'm able to connect to it, but can't discover services on iOS.": Could you show your code for that? Did you set the delegate? Do you keep a strong reference on the `CBPeripheral` (that's usually a common mistake on CoreBluetooth. The framework tends to not keep strong references, and since the delegates call are "async", it will forget the peripheral exists).?

Comment: Thats not the case. This behavior occurs in multiple apps from the Appstore. Likely a firmware issue as @jens-meder pointed out.

Comment: Hey @jim I can see you found a solution to your problem, could you expand on that a little bit please. I have the same problem except it only happens with one of our user's iPad (all other devices work perfectly)

Comment: Hi Simon. Since this happens only on one device, I think it's a different issue. Did the service UUIDs changed? Is it possible to connect with LightBlue? Have you tried point 1 from Jens answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds more like a problem in your firmware on the NRF52. I have been using NRF51 and NRF52 series for some years now and they definitely work with both iOS and Android devices.

**BLE advertising and service discovery**

Some general information on BLE advertising and service discovery:

A BLE advertising packet is very limited in size (31 bytes to be precise, not including the overflow area). That means you cannot advertise all the services your peripheral supports and the space might be shared with other information as well (appearance, name, manufacturer data, etc.). You do not even have to advertise any service at all or can even advertise services that your peripheral does not support. The service discovery works regardless of the advertised services.

**Debugging**

Some ideas for troubleshooting your problem:

1. iOS caches discovered services, characteristics and descriptors once they have been discovered until the next power cycle (turning Bluetooth off and on again or restarting the iOS device). This can lead to some unexpected behaviour if you have changed the underlying services etc. in your firmware but have not used the Services Changed Flag to indicate the change. Therefore, make sure that you send the Services Changed flag from your peripheral accordingly.
2. Try some of the examples that come with the NRF5 SDK and check if they work. If the examples work (which they should) there is definitely something wrong with your firmware.
3. Make sure that you handle the GAP and GATT events properly in your firmware. Both iOS and Android devices are not 100% compliant with the Bluetooth 4.0+ standard.  Nordic Semiconductor has already taken into account some of those quirks in their SDK and SoftDevice. You should definitely check the logs of the GAP and GATT events (basically the ble_evt_handler in your firmware) and refer to the Nordic Devzone where most of those quirks have been resolved already.
4. Check the permissions for reading and writing the service and characteristic metadata in your firmware. I had a similar problem where I accidentally set the read permission of my characteristics to `no access`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your good advice! Caching is not the problem, so a firmware issue seems quite likely! I'll invetigate on that.

Comment: Solved! The issue was that the firmware did not respond to `BLE_GATTS_EVT_EXCHANGE_MTU_REQUEST` and `BLE_GATTS_EVT_SYS_ATTR_MISSING`. This caused a timeout in CoreBluetooth, which closed the connection. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can't discover unadvertised services because unadvertised means not reachable, disable etc.

`LighBlue` show you `UUID` it's true, but it's **device UUID** not **service UUID** and that's the case.

To scan peripheral device you can use `CoreBluetooth`.
`CoreBluetooth` is a framework which provides the classes needed for your apps to communicate with devices that are equipped with BLE.

You can start scanning peripheral devices with `CoreBluetooth` using method `scanForPeripheralsWithServices:options:`. As a one of parameter of this method you need pass array of `services UUIDs`.
Discovered services will be available in method `centralManager:didDiscoverPeripheral:advertisementData:RSSI:`.

> On Android discovering services works just fine.

It's true. Android allow to scanning all available services around you. Unfortunately iOS not. Why? Apple explain that:

> Discovering all of a peripheral’s services and associated characteristics can negatively affect battery life and your app’s performance. Therefore, you should look for and discover only the services and associated characteristics your app needs.

So, to get `services UUID` (because that's what we need to perform scanning using `CoreBluetooth`) you can use Android app (kind of BLE scanner) or just read `services UUID` from box of your devices.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but what you describe is basically what I'm doing. Furthermore, the Apple explanation corresponds to the `discoverServices` function. By providing the UUIDs you're able to discover the services more quickly.

Comment: Thanks @Mateusz
Are you completely sure about that? Does that mean that when using iOS, I cannot use a service that is not being advertised? Do you have the link for that? I tried to find it, but I couldn't. Thanks a lot.